# blender , assign a texture via script with fixed name + variable

Tags: python, image, random, blender

here my issue. the script works fine in Blender 2.9 , until I put that random variable in the name. basically I need to link different textures to different files and materials via script . the problem is that I have label 21.jpg, label 34.jpg , label 345.jpg . that "random variable" is a placeholder, what do I need to put there so it succesfully loads the label texture , no matter which random number is in the name? thanks in advance

```
import bpy
import os
from random import *
from time import gmtime, strftime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty,StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty

os.getcwd()

def remap_texture_images():
    color_img = bpy.data.images['color']
    color_img.filepath = bpy.path.relpath("//" + "label" + random_variable + ".jpg")
    
remap_texture_images()
```

Comment: You should change the `random_variable` with the number that appears in the `.jpg` file you want to use, parsed as a string.

Comment: @JMA I have thousands of images and I need a system that needs to be able to process the texture named "label" no matter the number that follows

Comment: @JMA thanks for the help tho!

Comment: All the files are `label 1.jpg`, `label 2.jpg`, `label 323.jpg`, etc...?

Comment: @JMA yes. there are thousands of folders, in every folder only one image + 1 subfolder. I need to take only the image. I need to batch process all the folders, so no way to rename them all . every folder contain that only image. the name is always the same, but each one has a particular aleatory number attached to the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import os
import glob

import bpy

def remap_texture_images():

    color_img = bpy.data.images['color']
    list_of_images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
    if list_of_images:
        image_name = list_of_images[0]
        color_img.filepath = bpy.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name))
    else:
        print("No image with jpg extension in this directory.")

remap_texture_images()
```

Comment: thanks but I don't have to chose randomly between many, I need to chose the only one present in the folder. I have thousands of folders, each one containing one image and one subfolder. i need to batch process the images, one per folder. they all have same name + that nasty arbitrary number + extension. so far everything works perfectly, just that random number in the name messed everything up

Comment: But you want to process all the images in this `remap_texture_images` function or this function should process just one image in order to call it later on a loop through all the images?? I have edited my answer to process one single image that you have in the current directory

Comment: now this one looks very interesting, thank you so much for the effort ! it gives me error in line 9 , IndexError : list index out of range

Comment: This is just because there is some folder that does not contain any .jpg file. I have fixed it.

Comment: thanks a lot again . now it's working , but it gives in return "no image with jpg extension in this directory" even if instead of *.jpg I put the precise name of the image I am using for trying the system

Comment: what are the possible extensions for your images? in the case where it says "no image with jpg extension in this directory", what is the name of the image in that folder?

Comment: I tried with both .jpg and png, but nothing. it seems like it's not looking in the right folder to me. lets' say I am putting the image in a subfolder named "images" .. I changed the code like this "list_of_images = glob.glob('/./images/*.jpg')" but it still doesn't work

Comment: Use `glob.glob('./images/*.jpg')` without the first `/`.

Comment: I found out, I printed the working directory and it's working in the blender temp directory, that's why it can't find the images

Comment: Great! If this asnwer helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as valid, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but it should probably work:

```
def get_image_paths():
    from pathlib import Path
    return list(Path("path/to/thousands/of/folders").rglob("*.jpg"))

def remap_texture_images(paths):
    from random import choice
    color_img = bpy.data.images["color"]
    color_img.filepath = bpy.path.relpath(str(choice(paths)))

remap_texture_images(get_image_paths())
```

This assumes that your images are all JPGs, and stored in a relative folder named `label`.

It also assumes that you want to randomly select and apply any of the images in the folder, without taking repeats into account. In other words, multiple `color_img`s may have the same `filepath`.

Comment: thanks a lot , I am going to try now." return list(Path("/label")"   instead of "path" I need to write the path where I want to look for the images, right?

Comment: error "cannot choose from an empty sequence" thanks anyway!

Comment: thanks but I don't have to chose randomly between many, I need to chose the only one present in the folder. I have thousands of folders, each one containing one image and one subfolder. i need to batch process the images, one per folder. they all have same name + that nasty arbitrary number + extension. so far everything works perfectly, just that random number in the name messed everything up

Comment: @effe3D Hi there. Given this new information, I've edited my answer. I'm now using `rglob` instead of `glob`, so that images may be discovered recursively. Also, the string `"path/to/thousands/of/folders"` must be changed to the relative path of the directory containing the many many folders (with images and subfolders inside each). Do **not** change the `Path` part, only what goes inside the `Path(...)`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @effe3D I see, so you don't actually want to randomly select any images. You just want to discover all images (or paths to images), irrespective of what arbitrary number is included in their filenames. The code I've written should discover all images in all folders - you can simply ignore the `random.choice` segment of my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help! actually  I already have a loop that goes folder by folder, keeps records or where it has been , and it works already flawlessly where I don't have that random appendix to the name. what I really need is to be able to open that image even if I don't know it's complete name, since at every loop the paths are updated

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
import glob

import bpy

def remap_texture_images():
    os.chdir("insert_absolute_path_you_start_looking_for_images_here_from_here")
    path = os.getcwd()
    color_img = bpy.data.images['color']
    list_of_images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
    print (list_of_images)
    print (path)
    if list_of_images:
        image_name = list_of_images[0]
        color_img.filepath = bpy.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_name))
    else:
        print("No image with jpg extension in this directory.")

remap_texture_images()
```

thanks everybody for the help . @jma everything was pefect, but I suspected that blender used as working directory it's own temp one, so glob.glob would scan arount there, that's why the print path debug line. basically what I had to do is to add just a line , with os.chdir ,to make sure to start precisely from the folder I needed